# Table oid error. Select Query in postgresql returing table_oid in postgres query tool message and showing exception column does not exist

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a table and column is also there but when i am using select query in my i am getting id (my column name) does not exist Exception is coming.When i saw my db the in pg admin my column name is showing 
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1`

Comment: Please show us the SQL query which is generating the error.

Comment: Hi Nisha, and welcome. Please also  post the DDL for your table. You may wish to review the help section [ask]. If you follow that as a template for questions you are much more likely to get a satisfactory answer.